# Calling remote EJB3 without interface classes available

Tags: ejb-3.0

When calling remote EJB3 (Glassfish) from another EJB module, it is usual to have interfaces available, they are included as JAR file so that when you do JNDI lookup everything works as expected.

I have a situation where EJB3 JNDI name is determined at runtime, and my attempts to access the EJBs retrieved from JNDI in usual way fail, container complains ClassNotFound for remote interface classes. This is odd to me, since all the interface classes extend a parent interface for which I DO have a dependency in my calling EJB module, i.e.:

IParent ejbRef = (IParent) JndiLocator.getObject("jndinameRemote");

Is this possible with EJB3, without the need to have an exact remote EJB interface bytecode available in my JAR?

Bozo

Comment: This is a wild shot (both because of my limited knowledge, and the not too detailed description. What is the package setup? What is the error message? etc), but if you could try to place the interfaces on the global appserver (or domain) classpath, and it works that way, then you may have some issue because of different classloaders and etc.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is how JEE was designed, that you simply cannot make a generalized EJB client which calls any remote EJB for which you have JNDI name and interface parent class. It is very bad, I don't know why they didn't make this, it defeats the purpose of using EJBs for SOA-like, distributed services inside of your existing JEE-only infrastructure. I'm sure they wanted to use web services for this, but WSs are just unneeded overkill, they have all the technology right there in the application server to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though i am exactly not sure what the above setup is , I had a similar need of trying to invoke EJB when the client jars are not known during the compile time, infact in addition there is also no way for me to know what Application service is the EJB deployed at.

I had managed to do this by writing my  Customized Class Loader , the catch here is that the Class which in turn tries to invoke the EJB must be itself loaded using the Customized class loader along with all the necessary jars i.e client jar with interfaces and models and the application server specific client jar. 
I passed all the context properties as an input to my Invoker class to initialize context factory and invoke the bean.

These are high level steps to achieve this

Create Class EJBInvoker with method invokeEJB, you can pass it couple of Maps with properties for preparing context and Ejb interface , method , parameters classes , values and output class.
Use reflection to create instance of InitialContextFactory as well as Bean object , parameters and method invokation.
Add the above class to separate jar file and invoke the method with properties required from external project using a customized class loader.